# Zend form showing all errors / Zend form show error above each input field

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

For a form I'm using the following code:

```
class Application_Form_User_Register extends Zend_Form 
{
     public function init() 
     {
        $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
        $email->setLabel('Email adres: (*)')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addErrorMessage('Het veld Email adres is verplicht')
        ->addValidator('StringLength', false,array(6,100))
        ->addErrorMessage('Het email adres dient uit minstens 6 karakters te bestaan')
        ->addValidator('EmailAddress')
        ->addErrorMessage('Het veld Email adres moet een geldig email adres bevatten')
        ->addFilter('StringTrim');
        $this->addElement($email);
    }
}
```

When i post a wrong email address from this form, it shows all 3 error messages.

For example: if I post "thisisa@nonvalidadress", it shows all errors including the error "The email adres should be at least 6 characters long".

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Then a second question... Is there a way to show the error message above the corresponding input field?
Default the error message is shown underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the addValidator() method is the breakChainOnFailure metacommand. Just set if to true. So you would do

```
class Application_Form_User_Register extends Zend_Form 
{
 public function init() 
 {
    $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
    $email->setLabel('Email adres: (*)')
    ->setRequired(true)
    //->addErrorMessage('Het veld Email adres is verplicht')
    ->addValidator('StringLength', true, array(6,100))
    //->addErrorMessage('Het email adres dient uit minstens 6 karakters te bestaan')
    ->addValidator('EmailAddress', true)
    //->addErrorMessage('Het veld Email adres moet een geldig email adres bevatten')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim');
    $this->addElement($email);
}
```

}

This would break the validator chain if it failed.

Here is what the Zend Framework website says about custom validator messages:

Note: Providing Custom Validator Error Messages
Some developers may wish to provide custom error messages for a validator. The $options argument of the Zend_Form_Element::addValidator() method allows you to do so by providing the key 'messages' and mapping it to an array of key/value pairs for setting the message templates. You will need to know the error codes of the various validation error types for the particular validator.
A better option is to use a Zend_Translate_Adapter with your form. Error codes are automatically passed to the adapter by the default Errors decorator; you can then specify your own error message strings by setting up translations for the various error codes of your validators.

See this for details: [http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html)

Your second question, changing where the error message shows up, requires customizing the decorators on those form elements. You can definitely do it, and it's not as difficult as it seems at first. This article really helped me understand decorators: http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunatly the true option in the addValidator setting, is not the sollution. The error is still showing up :(

Comment: You should set each validator so they break the validator chain on faliure. Also, the custom error messages you are adding are Form element error messages not validator error messages. If you take out all of your ->addErrorMessage() you should see the chain break appropriatley. But of course your custom error messages would be gone. If you want customer error messages for the validators, I think you will need to extend the validator class and override the $_messageTemplate variable. Your other option is to use Zend_Translate, if you are just trying to display errors in another language.

Answer (score 2):

First qustion was answered. Second one should be somehow along this line:

```
$element->getDecorator('Errors')->setPlacement('prepend');
```

Answer (score 1):

Sudol is right about passing `breakChainOnFailure` parameter in case you want to stop validations after the first failure.

But your problem is in `addErrorMessage()` method which you call on the element. This method sets error messages that would be displayed in case element validation fails BUT it doesn't specify any connection between the message and the validator which failed. That's why you're getting all three messages each time any of your validators fails.

So what you need to do is to specify error messages for each validator instead of the element.

```
$emailValidator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
$emailValidator->setMessage( 'Het veld Email adres moet een geldig email adres bevatten' );

$email->addValidator( $emailValidator );
```

Alternatively, you might want to use [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.i18n.html) for translating standard error messages.